# Cannot get custom posts by category

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query

I'm building a function that uses `WP_Query` to query posts from a custom post type.

I can get posts just fine, as long as I don't try to include a category parameter.

This is the code I'm using now:

```
/*
 * Get albums by category
 */
function lml_albums_by_category( ) {

    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 6,
        'post_type' => albums,
        'category_name' => "new-release"
    ) ;


    $my_query = new WP_Query($args) ;

?>
    <?php if ($my_query->have_posts()) : ?>
        <section id="">
            <?php while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
                <article class="">
                    <h3><?php the_title()  ?></h3>
                    <p><?php  the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                    <p><a href="<?php echo get_permalink()  ?>">read more</a></p>
                </article>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </section> <!-- ENDS #...  -->
    <?php endif; ?>


<?php } ?>
```

If I omit the category parameter, I can get posts. But if I include it then I get no posts.

Posts of the custom type exist that have this category.

In the place of 'category_name' => "new-release" I have also tried:

```
'cat' => 430 // where 433 is the id of the category
```

And

```
'category__in' => 430
```

What could be going wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `cat` or `category__in` (for array of categories) instead of `category-name` and assign an ID to it:

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 6,
    'post_type' => 'albums',
    'cat' => 4,
);
```

I also would use single quotation `'` instead of double quotation `"` while setting a value. You are also missing quotations around your post type, which should be `'albums'` instead of `albums`.

For further reading, check the [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) page for `WP_Query`.

Comment: I probably should have added that I've tried 'cat', 'category__in'. I'll update the question to reflect this. Thanks.

Comment: @bob There is also a syntax error in your code. You should use `'albums'` instead of `albums`. This may cause issue and omit the next lines of code.